# How to fetch data from database by using Date in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I create a project on spring boot and project connected with H2 database .
Save the data in a database through the post Mapping rest API but parameter of our class `name`,`id`,`address` and `LocalDate` date.

I fetch the data data through using `getOrderById` method but i can't fetch the data between two dates.

Help me to fetch the data between two dates by using spring boot REST API.

Entity Class Order

Answer (score -1):

This query might help you to get the right result.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select  from Order o where o.date between :startDate and :endDate")
List<Order> getOrderById(@Param("startDate") LocalDate date1, @Param("endDate") LocalDate date2);
```